# Installing Google text-to-speech hd voices on sd card

Tags: link2sd, text-to-speech

I use the Google text-to-speech engine and it has the option to download high quality voices. Those are about 250 mB per file, and i barely have any internal memory left after i download them. Is there a way to move those to the SD card?

I have link2sd installed, but I would need to convert the engine from system app to user app to link the app files, and I suspect that this would cause all kinds of unforeseeable problems. I think that i would then also have to do the procedure of converting this app to system app and back for every rom update i flash, for the cyanogenmod update script to work -or maybe that step wouldn't be needed since userapps do not get touched anyway?

Well, even if the above would work, i would prefer a simpler solution.

Has anyone successfully moved those files to the SD card?

**UPDATE IN CASE ANYONE READS THIS:**

Apparently i would be able to move those files with the new paid version of link2sd, but i have by now decided not to use google's hd voices. There are better-sounding alternatives available for free on the market, and google voice search / google now use their own voice (i think it's network-synthesized) anyway.